# jqueryUI autocomplete "start typing" text?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Is there a simple way to get text such as "Please start typing to search" with Autocomplete on jQueryUI?

I didn't find anything [in the options](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#default) for the widget that does this automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**updated**
add

```
value="Please start typing"
```

to the input tag.
You also might want to add an onclick to the input to clear the text when you click on it
i.e.

```
$('#searchBox').click(function(){
    if( $(this).val() == 'Please start typing'){
        $(this).val('');
    }
});
```

here is a slight improvement if you only want it to be called the first time:

```
var watermark = 'please start typing';
var searchBox;

function setWatermark(){
     searchBox = $('#searchBox');
     searchBox.val( watermark );
     searchBox.bind('click',clearWatermark);
}

function clearWatermark(){
    if( $(this).val() == watermark){
         $(this).val('');
         searchBox.unbind('click',clearWatermark);
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
   setWatermark();
});
```

Comment: The clearing thing is my main concern, I don't want to clear the text after it's inital use.

Comment: That's great. It's unfortunate it's not internalized to the widget, it could be more efficient (in your case, it works every time the initial appears, rather than running any code for first usage -- but, making that improvement is a lot of work).

Comment: just made a small improvement to unbind clearing function after first use.

Answer (score 1):

Implementing watermark can lead to lot of manual work and most of your code may need re work depending upon business logic.

Try to go for the jquery watermark plugin.
Here this will give you a head start, include this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://labs.mario.ec/jq-watermark/jquery.watermark.js"></script>
```

and add this event handler

```
$(document).ready(function () {
         $('idOfTextBox').watermark('Please enter', { 
             className: 'lightText' 
         });
});
```

Specify the css style class name

```
.lightText{
//whatever color
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using

```
autocomplete( "result", handler )
```

and getting that text with a function 'handler'?